# Fatal Error:Maximum execution time of 120 seconds is exceeded

Tags: php

Error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZQkW.jpg

`Fatal Error:Maximum execution time of 120 seconds is exceeded`

The page loads very slowly.
The goal was to insert data and file to the table. But something does not let it. I will use my code as an example in this case.
So the user types their data here:

```php
<?php
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/tonevre/data_inc/functions.php";

use tonevre\general;
use tonevre\VideoUpload;
if(isset($_POST["addVideo"])) {
  $videoUpload = new VideoUpload;
  $response = $videoUpload->addVideo();
}
?>

  <label>Name your video!</label>
  <ul>
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required>
  
  <label>Description</label>
  <input type="text" name="descrip" placeholder="Tell the viewers about your video" required>
  
  <label>Upload your file</label>
  <input type="file" name="image" required>
  <button type="submit" name="addVideo">UPLOAD</button>
```

This data goes here (*addVideo* is a method from the class *VideoUpload*):

```php
 public function addVideo(){
        #This will insert the data to the table called vidup
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        $title = $_POST["title"] ? $_POST["title"] : "";
        $descrip = $_POST["descrip"] ? $_POST["descrip"] : "";
        $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"] ? $_FILES["image"]["name"] : "";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO vidup (title, descrip, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $paramType = "sss";
        $paramValue = array(
            ":title" => $title,
            ":descrip" => $descrip,
            ":image" => $image
        );


        $this->ds->prepare($sql, $paramType, $paramValue);

        $this->ds->execute($sql, $paramType, $paramValue);
        // if the title is empty echo the error message
        if(empty($title)) {
            $response["status"] = "error";
            $response["message"] = "Please enter a title";
            return $response;
        }
        if(empty($paramValue)) {
            $response["status"] = "error";
            $response["message"] = "There is a problem";
            return $response;
        }
```

I will also mention this, for more details:

```php
    public function prepare($query, $paramType, $paramArray)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $this->bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
        header("location: ../header.php");
    }
```

```php
   public function bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray = array())
    {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        $paramValueReference[] = &$paramType;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($paramArray); $i++) {         
            $paramValueReference[] = &$paramArray[$i];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array(
            $stmt,
            'bind_param'
        ), $paramValueReference);
    }
```

I couldn't find any solid enough explanation for the cause. A good explanation would help me and others in the future. Thank you.

Comment: What does `$this->bindQueryParams()` do with the value of `$paramArray[':image']`? Somewhere, I assume, something is handling the uploaded file? According to the stack trace in the screenshot, `:image` is not just the filename as in your code sample but the whole `$_FILES['image']` array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I guess that `$this->bindQueryParams()` binds the parameter ($paramArray[':image']) to the sql statement, just like the other parameters. ```public function bindQueryParams($stmt, $paramType, $paramArray = array())
    {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        $paramValueReference[] = &$paramType;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($paramArray); $i++) {         
            $paramValueReference[] = &$paramArray[$i];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array(
            $stmt,
            'bind_param'
        ), $paramValueReference);
    }``` And by UPfile, idk

Comment: That's interesting. Looks like that function is not intended to work with named placeholders, it expects the `$paramArray` to have numeric keys. But I personally don't see any reason this code should cause a timeout, just warnings and notices. You wouldn't happen to have Xdebug active with a breakpoint set, would you?

Comment: If my Xdebug is active? I disabled it to see what would have changed. I still get either *Fatal Error:Maximum execution time of 120 seconds is exceeded* or *Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 22569549824) (tried to allocate 21474836480 bytes)*, Both of these errors point to ***bindQueryParams***.  " function is not intended to work with named placeholders", maybe that's the cause?

Comment: OH I found something that might be relevant! ```Tonevre\DataSource->bindQueryParams( $stmt = class mysqli_stmt { public $affected_rows = 0; public $insert_id = 0; public $num_rows = 0; public $param_count = 3; public $field_count = 0; public $errno = 0; public $error = ''; public $error_list = []; public $sqlstate = '00000'; public $id = 1 }, $paramType = 'sss', $paramArray = [':title' => 'Please work for christ sake', ':descrip' => 'asdasdasdasd', ':image' => 'Amoung us room 1.mp4'] )``` Does these 0's mean something bad?

Comment: No, those 0's are expected since the statement has not yet been executed. That is correct. Honestly, with the code you've shared, I see no reason you would get a 120 second timeout. I also don't see why this would use up 22 GB of memory *and* try to allocate another 2 GB.

Comment: You should not edit your question with the solution, but post an answer (so you can mark your own answer as 'accepted answer')